# Monads - Purpose of Flatten

Tags: scala, monads, flatmap

So I've been doing some reading about Monads in scala, and all the syntax relating to their `flatMap` functions and `for` comprehensions. Intuitively, I understand why Monads need to use the `map` part of the `flatMap` function, as usually when I use a `map` function its on a container of zero, one or many elements and returns the same container but with the passed in function applied to all the elements of the container. A Monad similarly is a container of zero, one or many elements.

However, what is the purpose of the `flatten` part of the `flatMap`? I cannot understand the intuition behind it. To me it seems like extra boilerplate that requires all the functions passed to `flatMap` to create a container / monad around their return value only to have that container instantly destroyed by the `flatten` part of the `flatMap`. I cannot think of a single example where `flatMap` is used which can't be simplified by being replaced simply by `map`. For example:

```scala
var monad = Option(5)
var monad2 = None

def flatAdder(i:Int) = Option(i + 1)
def adder(i:Int) = i + 1

// What I see in all the examples
monad.flatMap(flatAdder)
// Option[Int] = Some(6)
monad.flatMap(flatAdder).flatMap(flatAdder)
// Option[Int] = Some(7)
monad2.flatMap(flatAdder)
// Option[Int] = None
monad2.flatMap(flatAdder).flatMap(flatAdder)
// Option[Int] = None

// Isn't this a lot easier?
monad.map(adder)
// Option[Int] = Some(6)
monad.map(adder).map(adder)
// Option[Int] = Some(7)
monad2.map(adder)
// Option[Int] = None
monad2.map(adder).map(adder)
// Option[Int] = None
```

To me, using `map` by itself seems far more intuitive and simple than `flatMap` and the `flatten` part does not seem to add any sort of value. However, in Scala a large emphasis is placed on `flatMap` rather than `map`, to the point it even gets its own syntax for `for` comprehensions, so clearly I must be missing something. My question is: in what cases is the `flatten` part of `flatMap` actually useful? and what other advantages does `flatMap` have over `map`?

Comment: If that is the example you always see then, wit all respect, the example _(and presumably the tutorial)_ is just bad, because as you say there is no point in creating a container to just flatten it. - Better examples for `flatMap` would be replacing nested loops using **List**, composing multiple functions that could not return a value using **Option**, composing validations using **Either**, composing async calls using **Future**. - In any case yeah, if you do not need to create an inner _"container"_  then don't do it, but the reality is that most of the time `A => F[B]` functions are common

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What if each element being processed could result in zero or more elements?

```
List(4, 0, 15).flatMap(n => primeFactors(n))
//List(2, 2, 3, 5)
```

What if you have a name, that might not be spelled correctly, and you want their office assignment, if they have one?

```
def getID(name:String): Option[EmployeeID] = ???
def getOffice(id:EmployeeID): Option[Office] = ???

val office :Option[Office] =
  getID(nameAttempt).flatMap(id => getOffice(id))
```

You use `flatMap()` when you *have* a monad and you need to feed its contents to a monad producer. You want the result `Monad[X]` not `Monad[Monad[X]]`.

Answer (score 2):

The idea behind `flatMap` is to be able to take a value of `M[A]` and a function `f` having a type of `A => M[B]` and produce an `M[B]`, if we didn't have a way to `"flatten"` the value then we'd always end up having an `M[M[B]]` which is what we don't want most of the time.
*(Yes, there are some cases that you may want an `M[M[_]]` like when you want to create multiple instances of `M[_]`)*